# meteor android app UI design

Tags: android-layout, meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to know best tool to design the UI which should be scalable on any device screens. I understand that meteor will take care of scaling but the image quality should not get affected i mean distorted or pixelate. Could anyone would suggest me any tool to design such UI assests.

Answer (score 0):

This library for you: https://github.com/ssomai/ScalableLayout

Here you just set the percentage scaling for all of your device type.

Comment: Thanks but how do I ensure that the assets doesn't get distorted when scaled to bigger screen size?